# Facebook birthday is not coming when logging in

Tags: facebook, response, facebook-login

I am using Facebook login button with JavaScript. Everything is working fine but my client needs to fetch "birthday" when any user log-in with Facebook.I have written the code but for some fb ids it is giving me the Birhtday while in some cases it is not giving.

I have checked answers on google already and have done almost everything but no success.

Here is my code I am using

**HTML CODE**

```
<a onclick="fb_login();" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <span>Log in with Facebook</span></a>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
function fb_login(){
        FB.login(function(response) {

            if (response.authResponse) {
                //console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                //console.log(response); // dump complete info
                access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
                console.log(access_token);
                user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    user_email = response.email; //get user email
                    first_name = response.first_name; //get first name
                    last_name = response.last_name; //get last name
                    full_name = response.name; //get last name
                    fb_id = response.id; //get id 
                    birthday = response.birthday; //get id 
                    alert(birthday);return false;
                    // you can store this data into your database

                    var data = {
                        action: 'mb_facebook_login',
                        user_email:user_email,
                        first_name:first_name,
                        last_name: last_name,
                        full_name:full_name,
                        fb_id:fb_id,
                        birthday:birthday

                    };

                    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(ajaxresponse) {
                        console.log(ajaxresponse);
                        if(ajaxresponse=='loggedin')
                        {
                            //location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                });
            } else {
                //user hit cancel button
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, { 
            scope: 'user_birthday,email,user_location'
        });
    }
```

I have also made my birthday to public also set the permission [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share) but it´s not working.

Please help me in this.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> Apps requesting more than public_profile, email and the user_friends permission must be reviewed by Facebook before those permissions can be requested from people.

That is one reason why it does not work for some people, without review it will only work for users with a role in the App (developer, tester, admin).

Another reasons could be that some users did not set a birthday. Not sure if that is possible, but it is worth testing.

Comment: Pardon! I did not get your answer. I just want to fetch user birthday when he logs in with FB.I have set my Birthday on FB and it is public.

Comment: then make sure the permission is approved by facebook. see changelog in my answer.

Comment: what to see in changelog? In changelog I can't find Birthday under removed fields

Comment: I have checked and everything is fine there.

Comment: what means "everything is fine"? did you get it approved by facebook or not? approval is NOT authorization.

Comment: how to get approval.I have seen that we can fetch birthday using fb login.Also I am getting it for one of my friend Facebook Profile but not getting in my profile

Comment: it´s all in the changelog, just follow the links: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login